# XmlStreamReader illegal state exception

Tags: java, xml, illegalstateexception, xmlstreamreader

I am trying to parse an xml file that contains rows that looks like the one show below:

```
<z:row TapID="4501" GesprekID="1358900" Onderzoek="123456789" NummerBeller="316987654321" TenaamstellingBeller="Pieter de Klerck, geboren 28-10-1980" NummerGebelde="316123456789" TenaamstellingGebelde="de Klerck B.V" Aard="Spraak" IMSIGebelde="098765432112345" Sessienummer="46" Wanneer="2014-11-09T10:49:25" Duur="39" ProductID="1000134498162" PaalGebeldeStartUniek="204-16-60076-33924" PaalGebeldeEindUniek="204-16-60076-33924"/>
```

I use the following code to parse the "row" records:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(file);
while (reader.hasNext()) {
  int event = reader.next();
  switch (event) {
      case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
      if ("row".equals(reader.getLocalName())) {
          for(int x = 0; x < reader.getAttributeCount(); x++){
             System.out.println(reader.getAttributeName(x) +": " + reader.getAttributeValue(x);)
          } 
      }
  }
}
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state is not among the states START_ELEMENT , ATTRIBUTEvalid for getAttributeName()
```

Can someone please explain to me why it is possible to get the AttributeValue but I keep getting errors when asked for AttributeName?

Comment: That code looks like it should work, are you sure you haven't cut out bits that may be relevant?

Comment: I don't think so, the code is part of a dropwizard webservice but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: I was thinking more about other `case`s within the `switch` that might fall through or something.

Comment: @biziclop there are no extra cases inside the switch.

Comment: Which StAX parser are you using? In my experience, only Woodstox is reliable.

Comment: I use javas.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader to parse the xml. I will have a look at the woodstox parser. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @MichaelKay using the woodstox library solved it for me! Again tnx for pointing me in the right direction!